# html code doesn't run in the browser, and only display the code

Tags: asp.net, html, browser, webserver

in order to find the server spec. i've created a file in the root dir in my website called spec.htm  and entered this content as i was offered by another user:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
   @ServerInfo.GetHtml()
    </body>
</html>
```

but i only get a copy of the code in my browser and it doesn't run it,
what the problem might be?

EDIT: i think that the problem is that i'm not using IIS.
is there a way to do so without using IIS?

thanks

Comment: What do you expect to happen? What programming language / platform are you expecting to run the code? What language is that code?

Comment: i want that the code will run the command "@serverinfo.gethtml()" which should display the details of the server such as: RAM, Processor etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the following article
http://www.asp.net/webmatrix/tutorials/14-introduction-to-debugging

> The ServerInfo  helper is a diagnostic tool that gives you an overview of information about the web server environment that hosts your page. It also shows you HTTP request information that is sent when a browser requests the page. The ServerInfo helper displays the current user identity, the type of browser that made the request, and so on. This kind of information can help you troubleshoot common issues.

1. Create a new web page named ServerInfo.cshtml.
2. At the end of the page, just before the closing  tag, add the following highlighted code.

   @ServerInfo.GetHtml()

***Note, it appears as though this is designed to run in IIS only and not on Linux / Apache servers.***
***Note, this is a RAZOR syntax so your system needs to be able to run Razor by installing the WebMatrix***

Comment: i've seen this site in my search, i will try this again, BTW i'm using asp.net not LINUX.

Comment: i think that my browser doesn't recognize the extention .cshtml so it doesn't work.

Comment: i've tried, it didn't work. what did you mean by RAZOR? is there a way of doing the same operation without RAZOR?

Comment: Can you double check to make sure you have [.NET 4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/net/) and [WebMatrix](http://www.asp.net/webmatrix) installed? Razor is part of WebMatrix

Comment: i don't know, my website is located on a paid server. if the code doesn't work it means that the serfver doesn't have webmatrix?

Comment: That's most likely the situation. Check out the [WebMatrix Getting Started](http://www.asp.net/webmatrix/tutorials/1-getting-started-with-webmatrix-and-asp-net-web-pages) section for more info.

Comment: ok i've read the article but if my server doesn't support WebMatrix then i can't use the code? i think that some of the servers has an option of installing software on the server, if so it is possible to install the software and then running the code?

Comment: yes, or ask the server admin if they're willing to install it... though I doubt they will since it's still in Beta.

Answer (score 1):

`@ServerInfo.GetHtml()` is a **Razor** view engine syntax. Try saving your file as `.cshtml` or `.vbhtml`

Comment: He also needs "WebMatrix" installed. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the `Content-Type` header correctly.  If not set to `text/html` or similar, the browser or framework may set the content-type to `text/plain` which will not render the html at all.

You can check this in [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) in the Net tab, expanding the response that is associated with the page you are serving, and looking in the Headers tab.  If the Content-Type header is anything besides `text/html` or `text/xhtml`, then you need to find a way to make your web server set that header properly

Comment: i entered this specific code in my html file as i was told.  are there any other lines i need to add? if so, which lines do i need to add? thanks for the fast reply!

Comment: i checked in firebug and in the response header the Content-Type    is : text/html, this is in two servers i'm using

Comment: What about viewing the source you are serving?  You don't need a plugin to check this, just pick view source, make sure the code isn't being escaped...

Comment: i didn't undetstand the answer, where should i check the source? on my website?

Comment: Open the browser, load the page, find the menu option that says `view source`.  read the source and make sure the code isn't being double escaped or some such nonsense.

Comment: i tried it and it display the source as expected, with the code line @serverInfo.getHtml()

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your webserver is not set up to serve HTML files through the ASP.NET interpreter.  Change the extension to `.aspx` (i.e., use the same code, but call it `spec.aspx`).

Comment: i tried what you told me but it still does the same thing, and copy the code into the browser.

Answer (score 0):

let me guess its just showing up "@ServerInfo.GetHtml()" on a webpage. This does nothing if you put it simply in a body tag of a html page. If you are running IIS make sure you are saving as .aspx and not .html

Comment: i think i've understand my mistake, i run the html file like this:  
www.mysite.com/spec.aspx directly from the browser and not by using IIS

Comment: is there a way to do so without using IIS?

Comment: @yishai well you need some sort of web server to host your code, and if you are using ServerInfo.GetHtml() which is asp.net related you will need a IIS.  Basically if your server is running Windows it will already have IIS, if its running Linux its probably running Apache, where ServerInfo.GetHtml() won't work.  

Though if you still want the specs you could just asking your host. (assuming you have one)

Comment: He also needs "WebMatrix" installed. See my answer

Comment: i've asked my host and they won't let me know those details and i need them for my project...

Answer (score -1):

See "yourhtmlsource.com/myfirstsite/myfirstpage.html"

I hope I am understanding the question and this helps. I found it on the web page given above.

When you double-click a file on your computer’s desktop, the computer knows what program to open the file in by checking the file’s “extension”. A txt file will open in a text editor.

You need to give your document a file extension of ”.html”, which will tell it to open the file in your web browser, such as Internet Explorer, Firefox or Safari.

Right now you should be editing your HTML page in a text editor, which normally saves files with the extension “.txt”. We want to make it save in “.html”. In your text editor click File → Save As…. If you use Microsoft Windows, there will be a box labelled “save as type”; change it to “all files *.*”. This means that you can save the data (in this case, some text) into any format. Now type in the name index.html for your file and click save. Ex: file.txt becomes file.html.